# How to extract image features using caffe matlab wrapper?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, caffe

Does anyone use the matlab wrapper for the caffe framework? Is there a way how to extract an 4096 dimensional feature vector from an image?
I was already following

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/432

and also tried to remove the last lines in imagenet_deploy.prototxt to remove layers as suggested in another forum on github.

But still when I run "matcaffe_demo(im, 1)" I only get a 1000 dim vector of scores (for the image net classes).
Any help would be appreciated
Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you might not be calling the correct prototxt file. If the last layer defined in the prototxt has the top blob of 4096 dimension, there is no way for the output to be 1000 dimension.

To be sure, try creating a bug in the prototxt file and see whether the program crashes. If it doesn't then the program indeed is reading some other prototxt file.

Comment: You are right in the mean time I found out that Matlab was not reloading the file "imagenet_deploy.prototxt" after changing it. I had to close and relaunch Matlab. Now it works :)